# How to fill the remaining space

Tags: css

I have a horizontal list with 4 items. The first item will be always `52px` wide. I want the remaining three items to be equal in width and fill up the remaining space.

How can I do this?

```css
.wa_talents .unlocks {
  width: 50px !important;
  background: black;
  font: normal 20px/52px"Palatino Linotype", "Georgia", "Times", serif;
  text-align: center;
}
.wa_talents .tier {
  list-style-type: none;
  border: 1px solid #221d19;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px #000;
  height: 52px;
  margin: 5px;
  clear: left;
}
.wa_talents .tier li {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 5px;
  width: 30%;
  /* THIS FAILS HARD*/
  height: 52px;
}
.talent {
  background: #000;
}
.talent .cell {
  padding: 4px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  opacity: 0.25;
}
.talent .name {
  width: 125px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 150%;
  color: #ffb100;
}
.talent.active .name {
  color: #fff;
}
.frame-36 {
  height: 36px;
  width: 36px;
}
.talent .icon-frame {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1px;
  background: #000 no-repeat 1px 1px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #434445;
  border-bottom-color: #2f3032;
  border-top-color: #b1b2b4;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.talent.active .cell {
  opacity: 1;
}
.talent.active {
  background: #5b2200;
  border-color: #ce5209;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px #ce5209 inset;
}
```

```html
<div class="wa_talents">
  <div class="tiers">
    <ul class="tier">
      <li class="unlocks">15</li>
      <li class="talent active">
        <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">
          <div class="cell">
            <span class="icon-frame frame-36"></span>
            <span class="name">Foo</span>
          </div>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="talent">
        <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">
          <div class="cell">
            <span class="icon-frame frame-36"></span>
            <span class="name">Bar</span>
          </div>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="talent">
        <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">
          <div class="cell">
            <span class="icon-frame frame-36"></span>
            <span class="name">Baz</span>
          </div>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <!-- HERE WILL BE SOME MORE ul#tier LISTS -->
  </div>
</div>
```

[View On CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xbvyjW)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before, `calc` isn't that widely supported. You could use `overflow:hidden` on an additional div containing the 3 right li's

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WbVamx

EDIT: wrong pen

Comment: @Brettetete oeps I linked the wrong one indeed, my bad. Updated. In the new one I left a little bit of margin in (the white space around the middle of the three), as it seemed you wanted that. It should be fairly easy to adjust though.

Answer (score 0):

Pure CSS : http://codepen.io/saig/pen/EaqBZd

Using JavaScript : http://codepen.io/saig/pen/raXqEJ

```
var mainId = document.getElementById('main');
var calcWidth = mainId.clientWidth - 52;
var list = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
for(i=0; i < list.length; i++){
  if(list[i].classList.contains("talent")){
    list[i].style.width=Math.floor((calcWidth/mainId.clientWidth*100)/(list.length-1))-1+"%";

  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The only way to do this in pure CSS is using calc(). You can check out the documentation and compatibility table here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc

Answer (score -1):

The simplest solution is to go with `calc` function. In your case it would be:

```
.wa_talents .tier li {
    float: left;
    width: calc((100% - 52px - 20px)/3);
    height: 52px;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

The rule is a little tricky: `52` is the width of the first `li`, then you also need to subtract total margin between items (`20px`).

[Support](http://caniuse.com/#search=calc): all major browsers and IE9+.

**Demo:** http://codepen.io/anon/pen/raXqZG